# Copy non blank cell in a range and paste to only one column

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to vb, please help me if you can. I have a range of data，starting from N5 to R24, all cells contain formulas, but only few of them are non-blank cells.

I want to copy only those non-blank cell to column AK，and add a string "/CA" to them。If cell in column N is ?bulk, add the number in column B first before adding "/CA",like below:

```
         B          N     O      P     Q     R     S           T
5                 1PLA  2PMC                                 1PLA/CA
6  123-01456789   1BULK                                      2PMC/CA
7                 1AKE                                1BULK/123-01456789/CA
8                                                             1AKE
9
10
```

The order in column AK doesn't matter that much, as long as it contains all non-blank cell data of range(N5:R24).

The following code is what I've tried, but I don't know how to add string or data in column B after paste:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Data")
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("N5:R24")
If cell.Value <> "" Then
cell.Copy
Range("AK" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, I don't pretty know how to write the code, I only know how to use `lastrow` to find the last row in a column, and I know that `specialcells` can be used to find constant and formulas, but I don't know how to find non-blank cells

Comment: If you have any code, or even made an attempt, please show it.  (See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me site, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will, I think, do what you are after.  (I wasn't sure whether column B was appended to the output **only** if you were processing column N, or whether you were processing any value on a row where column N contained "BULK".  My code does the latter, but I also included a commented-out version to do the former.)

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim newValue As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Data")

With ws
    'Initialise lastRow to be the last used row in column T
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop through every cell in the desired range
    For Each cell In .Range("N5:R24")
        'Start by setting the new value to be the old value
        newValue = cell.Value
        'Only process cells that aren't blank
        If newValue <> "" Then
            'Increment row counter for result
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            'Check if column N contains "BULK"
            If UCase(Mid(.Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value, 2, 4)) = "BULK" Then
                'If it does, append the contents of column B
                newValue = newValue & "/" & .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
            End If
            ''Alternate version if ONLY values in column N need to have column B appended
            'If UCase(Mid(newValue, 2, 4)) = "BULK" And cell.Column = 14 Then
            '    'If it does, append the contents of column B
            '    newValue = newValue & "/" & .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
            'End If

            'Append "/CA"
            newValue = newValue & "/CA"
            'Store result in column T
            .Cells(lastRow, "T").Value = newValue
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: WOW! Your explanation is extremely clear! I only need column B appended while processing column N, I'll change the code as you instructed by myself. I understand that "Ucase" is uppercase, so if all my values are in uppercase, then I don't need this function, am I right?

Comment: @TonyY - Correct - I only included the `UCase` to ensure that "5Bulk" or "5BULK" were both treated the same, so you can get rid of that if you know the data will always be uppercase to start with.  Also, I noticed in a comment you tried using a `Right(..., 4) = "BULK"` - if you know that the "BULK" will always be the last 4 characters, use that `Right` function instead of the `Mid` that I used.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to change `newValue = cell.Value` to `newValue = Right(cell.Value, len(cell.Value) - 1)` because I want to exclude the number of data (I am trying to paste the number in a new column next to T), but it failed. What am I missing?

Comment: @TonyY - If `cell.Value` is null (i.e. empty, "", blank, whatever you like to call it), then `Len(cell.Value)` will be `0`, and `Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)` will be equivalent to `Right(cell.Value, -1)` - which generates an error.  You should move that sort of statement to within the test for a non-null string, i.e. `newValue = cell.Value` `If newValue <> "" Then` `newValue = Right(newValue, Len(newValue) - 1)`.

Comment: So that's how it is, now I understand why it can't work. I have only just one more question: What if I change the only criteria "BULK" to multiple criteria, for example, if the mid(value) is one of 1,2,3 or 4, Then..... Should I write a new code for that (Can function `countif` use for this)? or I can do that just only adding some code like "OR" ?

Comment: @TonyY - I'm not sure what you mean by `if the mid(value) is one of 1,2,3 or 4` but you could certainly change a statement such as `If Right(newValue, 4) = "BULK" And cell.Column = 14 Then` to something like `If (Right(newValue, 4) = "BULK" Or Right(newValue, 3) = "XYZ" Or Left(newValue, 1) = "1") And cell.Column = 14 Then`.

Comment: Is there a easier way if I have too much criteria to add? I am trying to add another condition: `If (Mid(newValue, 2, 2) = "Q7" or "Q6" or "Q5" or "Q4" or "Q3" or "QP" or "QF" or "QF" or "A1" Then newValue = NewValue & "/M"` I understand I can still make that work using `OR` connecting all criteria like you have showed me, just wondering if there is a easier way to do it, like using `countif`(I know how to do it using function, but not vba ="= )...

Comment: @TonyY - For that sort of statement I would use `Select Case Mid(newValue, 2, 2)` `Case "Q7", "Q6", "Q5", "Q4", "Q3", "QP", "QF", "A1"` `newValue = newValue & "/M"` `End Select`.

Comment: @TonyY - Another way would be `If Instr("|Q7|Q6|Q5|Q4|Q3|QP|QF|A1|", "|" & Mid(newValue, 2, 2) & "|") > 0 Then` `newValue = NewValue & "/M"` `End If`.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each cell In Range("N5:R24")
If cell.Value <> "" Then
cell.Copy
Range("AK" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("AK" & LastRow + 1).value = Range("AK" & LastRow + 1).value & "/CA"
LastRow = LastRow + 1
End If
Next
```

You can implement also your other condition with an if clause. Also you will use & to join strings each other. 
Also you have to increment `LastRow` at each loop, otherwise it will stay same.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand why it always stay the same!  I've tried to add other condition with an if clause as you said, but it has failed. `Range("AK" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
If Right(cell, 4) = "bulk" Then
Range("AK" & LastRow + 1).Value = Range("AK" & LastRow + 1).Value & Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count)).Value & "/CA"
Else
Range("AK" & LastRow + 1).Value = Range("AK" & LastRow + 1).Value & "/CA"
End If`  Can you show me where is wrong?

Comment: I guess you found the answer in the other answer. :) it was because of "bulk" issue I guess.