# EXCEL 3 column into one

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns with text data in them, but with some blank cells as well.
I need to group the 3 columns together and get rid of the blank cells.
Not sure if it's better to first group the columns then get rid of the blanks, or the opposite.
Here's what I have so far.

1) Get rid of the blanks in Column B

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$64,(SMALL(IF(($B$7:$B$64)<>"",ROW($B$7:$B$64),""),ROW(B1)))),"")
```

2) Group the 3 column together, but blank cells still there

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$7:$B$101,ROWS(AD71:$AD$71)),IFERROR(INDEX($P$7:$P$102,ROWS(AD71:$AD$71)-ROWS($P$7:$P$102)),IFERROR(INDEX($AD$7:$AD$67,ROWS(AD71:$AD$71)-ROWS($B$7:$B$101)-ROWS($P$7:$P$102)),"")))
```

I just cant figure out how to put them together so that it does both.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this formula work: `=iferror(SUBSTITUTE(A1&B1&C1," ",""),"")`

Answer (score 1):

You don't show any examples of your source data and desired results. But if you are just joining the columns, with no delimiter, I suggest:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1)
```

or, if you have the `CONCAT` function:

```
=CONCAT(A1:C1)
```

If you need a delimiter, and you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can (for a comma delimiter) use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:C1)
```

If you want something else, show us some data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

after gouping together, *with delimators*, (lets pick / for now) do what [sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13696304/sam) said, but crucially,

`=SUBSTITUTE("/"&A1&"/"&B1&"/"&C1&"/","/ /","/")`, or,

```
=SUBSTITUTE("/"&A1&"/"&B1&"/"&C1&"/","//","/"),"/")
```

or better, all at once, `=substitute(SUBSTITUTE("/"&A1&"/"&B1&"/"&C1&"/","//","/"),""),"/ /","/")`

You could also mark it where your columns contained a blank or empty cell prior to concatonation by doing this too:

```
=substitute(SUBSTITUTE("/"&A1&"/"&B1&"/"&C1&"/","//","/was_blank/"),""),"/ /","/was_sneaky_space/")
```

Comment: & then you can either deal with these /was_blank/ and single delimiter markers with find-replace, or other-wise, later as you wish

Answer (score 0):

You've got us playing inspector Poirot with your initial wording of the question. but now I see where you getting at. [This](https://www.excelhow.net/copy-and-paste-only-non-blank-cells.html) is what you want. I prefer method 3. But all methods there work. You can combine in your spreadsheet to make it all work for you.

(Although a very lazy way, would be to copy-paste-special your results column , select just that column and then do remove duplicates just on that column, which would get rid of all blank cells (apart from 1) and that could suffice, whilst keep the order the same - but ignore that. Its just for you to know down the line. Although it would remove all duplicates; duplicates which you might have in the regroupings which you might want to keep in the results column wherever they appear. so don't do that if so. It's just an FYI.)

Any method [here - Copy and Paste Only Non-blank Cells](https://www.excelhow.net/copy-and-paste-only-non-blank-cells.html) will do it for you, but for your purposes & the way you are working, method 3 is the best bet imo. Tried & tested it for you. Paste the following array (CSE, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>) forumula in cell A2 and drag down.

```
=LOOKUP("xxxxx",CHOOSE({1,2},"",INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$9<>"",ROW($B$1:$B$9)),ROWS($B$1:B1)))))
```

**Word of warning:** if you do use method 3 or the simple macro sub (method 4) on that page too, and have any 'number only' formats in your regroupings columns, they will come out as empty blank cells (with the formula) or be skipped (with that short basic subroutine) in column A. So the concatenation with delimiter serves another purpose there. So, keep at least one delimiter in your regroupings if using any of these methods on column A, in column (column B), to avoid potential misses in column A and get around this).

**Alternative possibly better solution** , please see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709331/copy-non-blank-cell-in-a-range-and-paste-to-only-one-column) and [Ali Srn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711142/7275089). does what you want (also takes *any* filled cells as a result from the ranges. so that's good if you have any "number-only" filled cells in your regroupings columns.

I've tested it , adapted it for your needs, based on your image and ranges, and it puts all values from C,F and I, into a column A from cell A2 without any of the empty blank cells, as you need.

Actually, with this you don't even need your re-groupings column (although, based on your image, just change the range in the code below to just that "B1:B50" or "B1:Bwhatever" if you still want it). The code is pulling data out from ranges you specify ; Extract Col1, Extract Col2 and Extract Col3; and putting them directly in to results in the way and order you've requested.

```
Sub trytesting()
For Each cell In Range("c1:c50, f1:f50, i1:i50") 'change the row #s to suit your needs , in my test i did 50 row length data. just an example.
If cell.Value <> "" Then
cell.Copy
Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value = Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value
lastRow = lastRow + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

There's more you could do with this and look into, but I hope this is a start to helping you finish your project. But please be aware that SO is not a free "how-to" or coding service in any way. No one is here to give free or paid for advice/lessons which you can do yourself. More clarity in the initial questions with examples of what you have tried to do and pit falls you've received in the process would be strongly appreciated.

Comment: Inspector Poirot !!! LOL. Sorry ! its hard to attempt to think like you guys who know about that stuff. Your recommendation worked. After some tweaking, I was able to make it work with method 3. Works perfect now ! Thank you so much for your quick replies and support.